# My PC blacks out randomly. Screen says "No Signal", fans and LEDs are running

Tags: audio, memory, motherboard, gpu, fan

My PC blacks out randomly. After running for maybe 1hr or so the monitor blacks out and displays "No Signal". Audio also stops and I am unable to turn off the PC with keyboard shortcuts. The green LED stays on and cooling fans keep on running. Sometimes the screen turns purple and stays that way. I was starting to think it's onboard GPU but why would the audio and everything else would stop working if the GPU fails? This happens while working with Win 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LS. Sometimes the PC won't boot at all.

**Configuration:**
*Intel® Pentium® Processor E5700 3.00 GHz*

*MSI G41M-P26 Board*

*DDR3 Ram Stick in Slot 0.*

Tried Memtest86+ and tests passed with 0 Errors!!
Can someone point me at the right direction?

Update: I cleaned in and around the tower and all the cooling fans. I have unplugged and reset everything. Still the problem persists. Right now I am using the same PC to update this thread without any problem. After the display and everything stops I am having to cut the power to turn off the PC every-time.

Comment: Where does the audio come from? The screen via the HDMI cable? Or through regular speakers connected by 3.5mm cables?

Comment: What type of connection do you have between your computer and your monitor? Is it HDMI, DVI or VGA?

Comment: It's a regular VGA connection. Audio comes from the mother board audio port.